# How to convert a <table> to <div>s

Tags: css, html

That might sound silly but can't do it myself :(
Need your help guys.
How do I active the mark up from bellow but using DIVs (+CSS) instead of TABLE?

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="logo_left.gif" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <p><strong>THE TITLE!!!</strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="logo_right.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks in advance!

As some are asking I'm posting what I've tried so far... 
CSS

```
   <style type="text/css">        
      .header 
      {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom-width: 0px;
        background-image: url("Images/spriterepeatx.png"); 
        background-position: 0 -85px !important; 
        background-repeat: repeat-x; 
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 76px;
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
      }
     .LeftLogo a 
     {
        display: inline;
        float:left; 
        height:25px; 
        margin: 25px 0 25px 25px; 
        position:relative; 
        width:227px;
        background: url("Images/left_logo.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
     }
     .RightLogo
     {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background: url("Images/right_logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
     }         
     p.promo {
      font-size: 150% !important;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      white-space:nowrap;
    }

</style>
```

HTML:

> ```
> <body> <div class='header'>
>   <div class="LeftLogo"><a title="My company logo" href="http://www.mycompany.com"></a></div>
>   <div><p class="promo"><strong>MYProduct</strong> - Superb product</p></div>
>   <div class="RightLogo"></div> </div> </body>
> ```

Comment: What have you tried? Use css floats. SO is not a place to solve your homework ;)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show some effort. -edit: with Petr but slower :-)

Comment: @PetrMarek Just posted what I've tried so far :) It's not homework guys. I've just stuck here as I'm not a web-designer but server-side code developer and don't have relevant experince with divs and CSS layouts :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you start off by giving a `display: inline` style for your divs, because by default it is a "block", then you can position each of the div's as required.

A "block" div occupies the entire horizontal space, but with "inline" you can specify the space it needs to occupy. No give widths which can in "px" or "percentages" and the limit depends on your creativity.

Your above code in div's would be something like below:

```
<div class="divcolumn">
    <img src="logo_left.gif" />
</div>

<div class="divcolumn" style="text-align:center">
   <p><strong>The Title!!!</strong></p>
</div>

<div class="divcolumn">
    <img src="logo_right.gif" />
</div>
```

Now specify style like this:

```
.divcolumn { 
    display: inline;
}
```

You can even write a separate style for each column like "divcolumn-right", "divcolumn-center" and "divcolumn-left" and specify different styles. For example getting liquid layout specify width's like "30%", "40%" and "30%" in each of those styles respectively.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solve the problem. As right logo just desapears (please see my code above). :(

Comment: you've jumped straight away into a lot of "messy" css. Try the basic ones first, I will need time to correct your exact problem. See if you can build one with a simple css, if you can't let me know, meanwhile let me check on that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Navneeth's answer.
`<tr>` is a row and `<td>` is a column.
You can position `<div>` by declaring a number of styles and then applying them to the `<div>`.

```
<div class="somestyle-definition">
</div>
```

then in style sheet

```
.somestyle-definition
{
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:solid 2px white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. A starting point could be:

```
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="logo_left.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <p><strong>THE TITLE!!!</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="logo_right.gif" />
  </div>
```

And then in your css:

```
.float-left {
    float:left;
}
```

This just floats all your elements besides each other.
Thats not really beautiful and semantically not correct, but it works.

Comment: Looks much better! Thanks. But now they all look like glued together. Is there any way to make left logo to stick to left, right logo stick to the right and the title remain in the middle taking all free space?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h1>The title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}

h1::before {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    content: url( http://placekitten.com/100/100 );
}

h1::after {
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
    content: url( http://placekitten.com/120/100 );
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsbin.com/oqiyul/2

Answer (score 0):

I use css to accomplish this myself. I have general table, row, and cell styles, and then I incorporate specific additional styles for presentation (alternating row colors, selected row boldness, etc). Here is the html for one of my tables (scrubbed):

```
<div class="table grid">
    <div class="tr gridHeader">
        <div class="tdColumn1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" />
        </div>
        <div class="tdColumn2">
            <strong>Header1</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="tdColumn3">
            <strong>Header2</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="tdColumn4">
            <strong>Header3</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="tdColumn5">
            <strong>Header4</strong>
        </div> 
    </div>


    <div class="tr tdWhite">
        <div class="tdColumn1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
    </div>

            <div class="tdColumn2">
                    <p>Data1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn3">
                    <p>Data2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn4">
                    <p>Data3</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn5">
                    <p>Data4</p>
            </div>
    </div>   

        <div class="tr tdGrey">
            <div class="tdColumn1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn2">
                    <p>Data1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn3">
                    <p>Data2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn4">
                    <p>Data3</p>
            </div>

            <div class="tdColumn5">
                    <p>Data4</p>
            </div>
    </div>   

</div>
```

And here is the css that governs the layout of these divs. I've omitted most appearance related stuff (fonts, colors, etc). You'd have to make your own adjustments to width, percentages, etc.

```
div.table
{
    display: table;
}

div.tr
{
    display: table-row;
}

div.tdColumn1, div.tdColumn2, div.tdColumn3, div.tdColumn4, div.tdColumn5
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 4px;
}

div.tdColumn1
{
    width: 25px;
}

div.tdColumn2
{
    width: 20%;
}

div.tdColumn1, div.tdColumn2, div.tdColumn4, div.tdColumn5
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.tdColumn1, div.tdColumn5
{
    text-align: center;
}
```