# Div cannot attach to its neighboring div

Tags: html, css

If you look at the image you can see that `the box that contains #1 has a little margin to its right and then following that comes the club picture`. I want the image to attach itself to the div to its left so theres no space in between. I've tried just about everything and cannot figure it out. **I'm a big CSS newbie FYI**

[image]

**I'm still very new to CSS but I'm trying to push the image over to the left and sort of attach itself to the box with the number inside**

Here is my resulting HTML:

```
    <table class="featuredclub" id="featuredclub-comments">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%" class="rating"><div class="ratingnumber">
                        <span class="ratingpositiontext"><span
                            style="margin-top: 15px">#8</span></span>
                    </div></td>
                <td width="15%" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 1px"
                    class="imagetd"><div class="ratingimage">
                        <div style="margin-top: 6px">
                            <img style="height: 80px; width: 80px" class="featuredavatar"
                                src="/img/featuredtmp.png">
                        </div>
                    </div></td>
                <td width="75%" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10px"><span
                    class="featuredclubname">Alex's</span><span
                    class="featuredclubaddress">584 Washington st</span><span
                    class="featuredclublocality">Stoughton, MA 02072</span><span
                    class="featuredclubphone">781.344.2175</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    @CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

    span.value {
        margin-right:-10px;
    }
    .viewallbutton{
        display:inline;
        margin-top:2px;
        margin-left:2px;
    }
    h2.sectionlabel{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .banner{
      position: relative;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 1200px;
      height: 66px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding-top:15px;
      padding-bottom:0px;
      padding-left:25px;
      padding-right:25px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /**
      border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-bottom:none;
      */
      border:0px;
      border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0;
      font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    .banner h2{
      font: 32px/32px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-top:5px;
      padding-bottom:15px;
    }
    div.banner-container1{
        width:90%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        padding-left:25px;
    }
    div.banner-container2{
        width:90%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        padding-left:25px;
        /**padding-left:25px;*/
    }
    div.banner-container div.innerclubbox{
        background-color:#ffffff;   
    }
    .tabledatalabel{
      font: 20px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #606060;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      /**text-transform:capitalize;*/
      padding-top:5px;  
    }
    .row {
      position: relative;
      /**height: 750px;*/
      height: 450px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      /**padding-top:20px;*/
      padding-top:10px;
      padding-bottom:0px;
      padding-left:0px;
      /**padding-right:25px;*/
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /**border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
      font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;     
    }
    p .clear{
      clear:both;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;  
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub,
    .section2 table.featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
        margin-top:-5px;
        /**margin-left:25px;*/
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub .rating,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .rating {
        /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
        /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
    }

    .section1 table.featuredclub .image,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .image {
        /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
        /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    .ratingnumber{
        font-size: 42px;
        margin-left:14px;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        /**padding-left:15px;
        padding-top:15px;*/
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span,
    .section2 .featuredclub span {
       line-height: 85px;
    }
    .ratingpositiontext{
        margin-right:15px;
        margin-top:55px;
    }
    .section1 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage,
    .section2 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage{
        font-size: 26px;
        margin-left:0px;
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub .featuredtext{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
        display:inline-block;   
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.rating{  
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
        /**display:inline;*/
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.text{    
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        /**width:71px;*/
        height:71px;
        display:inline;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname
    {
        clear:both;
        color:#120006;
        float:left;
        font: 22px/22px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubphone,
    .section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubphone
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        font: bold 12px/12px Arial, Helvtica, Sans-serif;
        margin-top:2px;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span p.rating,
    {
        margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:71px;
        height:71px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar{
        margin-top:-27px;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        margin-left:69px;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar{
        margin-top:-27px;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        margin-left:69px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 36px;
        color:#bd673a;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 36px;
        color:#bd673a;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    .section1 .featuredclub span{
        /**margin-left:25px;*/  
    }

    .section2 .featuredclub span{
        /**margin-left:25px;*/  
    }

    .section1 {
      width:50%;
      /**border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
      float:left;  
      box-sizing: border-box;   
    }

    td {
        font:14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
    }

    .section2 {
      width:50%;
      /**border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
      float:left;  
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .section1 h2{
      font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-left:17px;
      padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    .section2 h2{
      font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
      color: #120006;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding-left:17px;
      padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    td {
        text-align:right;
    }
    td.imagetd{
        text-align:left;
    }

    .progress-bar .horizontal {
      float: left;
      height: 45px;
      width: 100%;
      /**padding: 12px 0;*/
    }

    .progress-track {
      position: relative;
      width: 30%;
      height: 13px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      float:right;
      margin-left:-20px;
    }

    .progress-fill {
      position: relative;
      background: #2272af;
      height: 13px;
      width: 50%;
      color: #2272af;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 20px;
      border-radius:0px 4px 4px 0px;
      /**border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
      /**border-radius-top-right:5x;
      border-radius-bottom-right:5px;*/
    }

    /**tr td { padding-top: 1px }*/
    .ratingpositiontext{
        color:#e8620d;
        font: 42px/44px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this. I've tried and cannot figure out how to get the **image to attach to the number div**

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the display:block css attribute on the image.

Comment: @NaderDabit That didn't seem to work. Like I said I'm a big newbie with CSS. I think it has to do with how I am setting my margins and the image is being constrained

Comment: try removing parts of your code, so you can localize only your problem, then please ask again, only with certain bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is probably coming from the spacing between your table cells. Try using the CSS:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td { margin: 0; }
```

or the brute-force method:

`<table cellspacing="0">`

update: fixed for me with:

```
.featuredclub { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5vdjzud/

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Just out of curiosity, instead of creating a new question, my senior says the image div is sitting 1px above the number div. I can't seem to adjust it with margin settings. Do you know how to resolve this question too?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I have added border to table to just show how the TDs are laid out. Feel free to remove it if that bothers. If I have not understood your question then please highlight the problem in your sample image.

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
 span.value {
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.viewallbutton {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
h2.sectionlabel {
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 66px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /**
      border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
      border-bottom:none;
      */
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
.banner h2 {
  font: 32px/32px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
  color: #120006;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
div.banner-container1 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
div.banner-container2 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  /**padding-left:25px;*/
}
div.banner-container div.innerclubbox {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.tabledatalabel {
  font: 20px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
  color: #606060;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  /**text-transform:capitalize;*/
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
  /**height: 750px;*/
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /**padding-top:20px;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  /**padding-right:25px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /**border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
  font: 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
p .clear {
  clear: both;
}
.section1 .featuredclub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
}
.section1 table.featuredclub,
.section2 table.featuredclub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
  margin-top: -5px;
  /**margin-left:25px;*/
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.section1 table.featuredclub .rating,
.section2 table.featuredclub .rating {
  /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
  /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
}
.section1 table.featuredclub .image,
.section2 table.featuredclub .image {
  /**margin-top:-5px;
        margin-left:25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;*/
  /**background-color:#ffffff;*/
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.ratingnumber {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /**padding-left:15px;
        padding-top:15px;*/
}
.section1 .featuredclub span,
.section2 .featuredclub span {
  line-height: 85px;
}
.ratingpositiontext {
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.section1 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage,
.section2 table.featuredclub .rating div.ratingimage {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.section1 .featuredclub .featuredtext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
  display: inline-block;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span p.rating {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  /**display:inline;*/
}
.section1 .featuredclub span p.text {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /**width:71px;*/
  height: 71px;
  display: inline;
}
.section2 .featuredclub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname,
.section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubname {
  clear: both;
  color: #120006;
  float: left;
  font: 22px/22px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress,
.section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubaddress {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
  color: #000000;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality,
.section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclublocality {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
  color: #000000;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span.featuredclubphone,
.section2 .featuredclub span.featuredclubphone {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font: bold 12px/12px Arial, Helvtica, Sans-serif;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.section2 .featuredclub span p.rating,
{
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
}
.section1 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar {
  margin-top: -27px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 69px;
}
.section2 .featuredclub p.rating img.featuredavatar {
  margin-top: -27px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 69px;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #bd673a;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.section2 .featuredclub span p.rating span.rating-number-box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #bd673a;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.section1 .featuredclub span {
  /**margin-left:25px;*/
}
.section2 .featuredclub span {
  /**margin-left:25px;*/
}
.section1 {
  width: 50%;
  /**border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td {
  font: 14px/20px AdlWebNorm, Sserif;
}
.section2 {
  width: 50%;
  /**border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;*/
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.section1 h2 {
  font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
  color: #120006;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.section2 h2 {
  font: 22px/24px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
  color: #120006;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
}
td.imagetd {
  text-align: left;
}
.progress-bar .horizontal {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  /**padding: 12px 0;*/
}
.progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 13px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  background: #2272af;
  height: 13px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #2272af;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato", "Verdana", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  /**border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
  /**border-radius-top-right:5x;
      border-radius-bottom-right:5px;*/
}
/**tr td { padding-top: 1px }*/

.ratingpositiontext {
  color: #e8620d;
  font: 42px/44px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table class="featuredclub" id="featuredclub-comments" border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rating">
        <div class="ratingnumber">
          <span class="ratingpositiontext"><span style="margin-top: 15px">#8</span></span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 1px" class="imagetd">
        <div class="ratingimage">
          <div style="margin-top: 6px">
            <img style="height: 80px; width: 80px" class="featuredavatar" src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10px">
        <div class="featuredclubname">Alex's</div>
        <div class="featuredclubaddress">584 Washington st</div>
        <div class="featuredclublocality">Stoughton, MA 02072</div>
        <div class="featuredclubphone">781.344.2175</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the padding from your currently implementation you would need to add:

```
/* remove padding between cells */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* remove padding within cells */
td {
    padding: 0
}
```

Ultimately you should really reconsider using a table here, this is not displaying tabular data and you can achieve this easily without one using floating or inline elements: [How to convert a <table> to <div>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212455).